# Show that if $f$ maps the straight lines to the straigth lines then $f$ must be an affine map

Tags: linear-transformations, mathematical-physics, affine-geometry

Let $E$ be a 3-dimensional metric space that isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$ by the bijective isometry $x:\ E\longrightarrow\mathbb R^3$. Then, we can define a vectorspace structure for $E$ by
\begin{align}
\oplus:\ E\times E&\longrightarrow E
\\ (p,q)&\longmapsto p\oplus q=x^{-1}\big(x(p)+x(q)\big)
\\ \odot:\ \mathbb R\times E&\longrightarrow E
\\ (k,p)&\longmapsto k\odot p=x^{-1}\big(kx(p)\big).
\end{align}
$\big(E,\oplus,\odot\big)$ then is a vector space on $\mathbb R$, or $\big(E,+,\cdot\big)$ without any confusion.

Further, we can construct a vectorspace structure for $\,\mathcal N=\mathbb R\times E\,$ by
\begin{align}
(s,p)+(r,q)&=\Big(s+r,x^{-1}\big(x(p)+x(q)\big)\Big)
\\ k\cdot(s,p)&=\Big(ks,x^{-1}\big(kx(p)\big)\Big).
\end{align}
Here, we shall call $E$ a *Newtonian space* and $\mathcal N$ a *Newtonian spacetime*.

Now, with $0\in I\subseteq\mathbb R$, we define a straight line in $E$ is a map
\begin{align}
\alpha:\ I&\longrightarrow E
\\ s&\longrightarrow \alpha(s)=sp+ q,\ \text{ for some }p,q\in E.
\end{align}
and a straight line in $\mathcal N$ is a map
\begin{align}
\gamma:\ I&\longrightarrow\mathcal N
\\ s&\longrightarrow \gamma(s)=\big(as+b,sp+q\big),\ \text{ for some }p,q\in E.
\end{align}

Assume a diffeomorphism that we call an *inertial frame*
\begin{align}
f=(t,x):\ \mathcal N&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^4
\\ (s,p)&\longmapsto \Big(t(s,p),x(s,p)\Big)=\big(t_s(p),x_s(p)\big)
\end{align}
that turns every straight line of the form $(s,ps+q)$ in Newtonian spacetime $\mathcal N$ to straight line in $\mathbb R^4$.

I knew that there's a result that if the Newtonian spacetime $\mathcal N=\mathbb R^4$, then $f$ is an affine transformation $f(x)=Ax+b$. The proof of this claim is followed by these steps

1. By composing with an appropriate translation we can assume without loss of
   generality that f maps the origin to the origin. Therefore we just have to prove
   that f is linear.
2. Give a plane $P\subset\mathbb R^4$ and $d_1,d_2,d_3\subset P$ are 3 straight lines which intersect pairwise. Then $f(d_1),f(d_2),f(d_3)$  are straight lines which intersect pairwise, thus they form a plane $Q$.
3. We claim that $f(P)\subseteq Q$ and by a same argument, $Q\subseteq f(P)$. Hence, $f$ maps the planes to the planes.
4. We show that $f$ takes parallelograms to parallelograms, this implies $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v),\  \forall u,v\in\mathbb R^4$.
5. Since $f$ is continuous, we conclude $f$ must be linear.

But I wonder if we can tell that $f$ is an affine map in the general context where $E$ needs not to be $\mathbb R^3$ ?

Could anyone enlight me with some idea or some counter example for this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/46860/516428

Comment: Your notations are overcomplicating your post. Just let $E:=\Bbb R^3$ and $\mathcal N:=\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I am writing an article of spacetime topic, and in my article I define the Newtonian space $E$ is any metric space that isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$ but not necessarily to be $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: That makes no difference. And what are you calling "the general context" in your final question? I mean: if $E$ is just "isometrically isomorphic" to $\Bbb R^3$ instead of being $=$, the proof is the same.

Comment: @AnneBauval if $E$ is not $\mathbb R^3$, how can one define the invertible matrix $A$ such that  $$f(s,p) = A\begin{bmatrix}s\\ p\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}s_0\\ p_0\end{bmatrix} $$ for $(s,p)\in\mathbb R\times E$ ?

Comment: @AnneBauval: your MO link doesn't quite answer the question, because PermQI's straight lines in $\cal N \simeq \Bbb{R}^4$ exclude lines in $\{0\}\times \Bbb{R}^3$. I don't think that's difficult to fix.

Comment: @RobArthan Why do my straight lines in $\mathcal N$ exclude lines in $\{0\}\times\mathbb R^3$ ?

Comment: @RobArthan I was aware of that and left it to the OP as presumably easy.

Comment: @AnneBauval what  is the OP ?

Comment: It is either the Original Poster (you) or the Original Post.

Comment: @AnneBauval but how do you define an invertible matrix $A$ such that $f(s,p) = A\begin{bmatrix}s\\  p\end{bmatrix}+b$ for $(s,p)\in\mathbb R\times E$ ?

Comment: Your parametric definition of a line excludes lines with the parametric form $s \mapsto (0, sv)$ for $v \in \Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @RobArthan you are right, I didn't notice that when I stated the definition for lines in $\mathcal N$. At that time, I just simply think that every line of the form $(as+b,ps+q)$ in $\mathcal N$ can be transformed to a line of the form $(s,ps+q)$, so I made that definition. With you pointed out that, I think I need to fix my definition for the lines in $\mathcal N$.

Answer (score -1):

Every straight line can be represented parametrically
$ P_{t} = A +vt $ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ v$ is from asociated vector space
If $f$ is affine of course
$f(P_{t})= f( A +vt) = f(A)+ g(vt)= f(A) + g(v)t $ so f maps lines into lines
Now we consider arbitrary transiguration wich for every $A + vt $ gives $ B + ut $
To prove affinity we have just prove for distinct $s$ and $t$"
$f(A + vt ) - f( A + vs ) = u(t-s) $

So we have just to prove for every vector
$v$ $g(v) = vt $ is,linear trasformation becaulse $f(x) = f(x_{0}) + ut $ is affinic space for every $u$

Comment: I have a question, if a linear map $T$ takes the parallelograms to parallelograms, then why this implies $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ ?

Comment: If $u,v$ are linearly independent, we can use the parallelogram's property to show that $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$.  But what about the case $u,v$ are not linearly independent ?